# Trying to divide 2 separate queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, division

I've seen a couple posts on dividing 2 separate queries that seemed helpful but I am still having trouble dividing these two queries. I wrote different sub queries and followed some examples, but I just keep getting errors as the example queries seemed more straight forward (no Joins).

Here is the first query:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(s.created_at) AS year,
    COUNT(*) AS pre_sub_buys
FROM subscription_users s
INNER JOIN users u
ON s.user_id = u.uid
LEFT JOIN canvases c
ON u.email = c.ref_email
WHERE c.is_paid=1 AND c.date_created < s.created_at
GROUP BY year;
```

And I am trying to divide this by:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(s.created_at) AS year,
    COUNT(s.created_at) AS subscribers
FROM subscription_users s
LEFT JOIN canvases c
ON c.entries_updated_at = s.updated_at
GROUP BY year;
```

Essentially, I am looking to find the yearly average between presubscription purchases and subscribers.

Can anyone direct me in the right direction on how to properly do this?

Thank you so much,
Jonathan

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE` clause on the right-side table of the left join is effectively an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Sample table data and expected result would help. (Make it easy to assist you, [mcve].)

Comment: What do you mean "divide this by" "to find the yearly average"? Neither query returns a number. This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly".

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Hey @philipxy I apologize for the lack of clear information. My original task was to figure out how many customers made a purchase from out website before actually signing up for a subscription. I was able to achieve this, but what I am trying to do particularly with these 2 queries is figure out the yearly total of pre subscription buys compared to the total number of subscribers.

Comment: @philipxy ie: In 2019 we had a total of 39 purchases by customers who eventually subscribed (results of 1st query). The 2nd query then calculates that we had a total of 148 subscribers. Now I am trying to get MySQL to divide 39/148 to show me the result of 26%.

Comment: Anyways, it was solved below. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Your comments aren't clear--"get MySQL to divide 39/148" doesn't say what output you want per input. You were lucky that someone guessed. PS SO Qs & As are a resource for others. An unclear question is a poor resource. Please consider editing your questions until they deserve upvotes. Most code questions including this one should have a [mre].

Comment: @philipxy Oh, alright I'll follow those example guidelines from now on before I post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this using Conditional Aggregation:

```sql
SELECT 
    YEAR(s.created_at) AS year,

    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.is_paid=1 AND c.date_created < s.created_at THEN 1
               ELSE NULL
          END) AS pre_sub_buys, 

    COUNT(s.created_at) AS subscribers, 

    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.is_paid=1 AND c.date_created < s.created_at THEN 1
               ELSE NULL
          END) / COUNT(s.created_at) AS pre_sub_buys_divided_by_subscribers

FROM subscription_users s
INNER JOIN users u
        ON s.user_id = u.uid
LEFT JOIN canvases c
        ON u.email = c.ref_email 
GROUP BY year;
```

Comment: This worked 99% as I have 148 subscribers and this query gave me 309. I tweaked it slightly and added a DISTINCT clause: 'COUNT(DISTINCT(s.created_at)) AS subscribers'. It now calculates my numbers perfectly. Thank you for this and for the lesson as well!